# WPF dataGrid tool tip service

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, tooltip, wpfdatagrid

So I have a `DataGrid` and I would like to be able to display data from what ever cell the mouse is over using the `ToolTip` service. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Here is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource DataGridRow}" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                        EnableColumnVirtualization="True" />
```

And here is what I have tried, but my app wont load the `DataGrid` when I add this.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Value}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this in your resources

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content.Text}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: i get an error on the setter proper when i try to load up the datagird

Comment: Would you please specify the error ? It worked perfectly for me without any error.